# Throttling connections on 429 errors in WebClient mechanism, best practice?

Tags: c#, .net

I know theres a better way to do this, I'm sure my mechanism is actually wrong and would crash if it consistently failed. Is there a better practice to a retry mechanism, other than the way I've done it?

Since I'm relying on the response the web client gives, I never want to miss a response from this web client. I'm converting a list on a new system a website has. I know flooding it with traffic will consistently result in a 429 error (Too many connections) so the correct thing to do is throttle, right?

Here is my mechanism.

```
public static string GetUsernameFromId(long userId)
{
    using (var client = new WebClient())
    {
        try
        {
            // removed business logic, minimal example
        }
        catch (WebException we)
        {
            if (we.Message.Contains("429"))
            {
                return ThrottleConnections(userId);
            }

            throw;
        }
    }
}

public static string ThrottleConnections(long userId)
{
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1 * 60 * 1000);
    return GetUsernameFromId(userId);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah i wouldn't be doing this with recursion, its asking for trouble.

This would probably be better, in a while loop with a retry count and a limit and some nice asycnrony, also i have left a lot to the imagination, you probably want to throw on max retries

```
public static async Task<string> GetUsernameFromId(long userId)
{
   var retries = 0;
   while (retries++ < MaxRetries)
   {

      using (var client = new WebClient())
      {
         try
         {
            ///await client.OpenReadTaskAsync();
            ///blah
            /// 
            break;
         }
         catch (WebException we)
         {
            if (!we.Message.Contains("429"))
            {
               await Task.Delay(waitTime);
               continue;
            }

            throw;
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `Thread.Sleep` is almost never a good idea, better use a timer or `await Task.Delay(...)` as it does not block.

Your best bet is using a library that can provide retries etc. in a well thought manner. For example [Polly](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly) is a well known library. It supports time based retrying as well, see [the docs](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly#retry)

```
// Retry, waiting a specified duration between each retry
Policy
.Handle<SomeExceptionType>()
.WaitAndRetry(new[]
{
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3)
});
```

If the response has a Retry-After header you can [use that as well](https://github.com/App-vNext/Polly/wiki/Retry#retryafter-when-the-response-specifies-how-long-to-wait):

> Some systems specify how long to wait before retrying as part of the fault response returned. This is typically expressed as a Retry-After header with a 429 response code.
>
> This can be handled by using WaitAndRetry/Forever/Async(...) overloads where the sleepDurationProvider takes the handled fault/exception as an input parameter (example overload; discussion and sample code).
>
> Some SDKs wrap RetryAfter in custom responses or exceptions: for example, the underlying Azure CosmosDB architecture sends a 429 response code (too many requests) with a x-ms-retry-after-ms header, but the Azure client SDK expresses this back to calling code by throwing a DocumentClientException with RetryAfter property. The same overloads can be used to handle these.

If you do not want to use an external library than at least you can browse the source to get an idea how to deal with retries.